# Laravel get relationship of relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to retrieve additional data from a relation. 
But so far I have not been able to do this. It is about a group that contains products. 
I want to retrieve data related to these products. So far I have not found a solution to realise this.

Tables with fields:

**lager_stock_booking_groups**
id,datetime

**lager_stock_booking**
id, lagerProductId, stockBookingGroupId(id from Table lager_stock_booking_groups)

**lager_products**
id(lagerProductId from Table lager_stock_bookings)

```
$bookingGroup = LagerStockBookingGroup::with('stockBookingProducts')->where('id', '=', $id)->orderBy('dateTime', 'desc')->get();
```

This code get me the groups and Products liek this:

Group[ID 23]
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3

I have only the Product-ID's. How can get additional Data of Products from Table lager_products?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can get with relation :

```
$bookingGroup->stockBookingProducts
```

or use `join`

Comment: thats work fine.
```
$bookingGroup->stockBookingProducts
```

I also want data from the model "lager_products".

In 

```
$bookingGroup->stockBookingProducts
```

i have lagerProductId. 

I also want the name from the model "lager_products" to this lagerProductId.

Comment: Use the with function. Model::with(‘lager_stock.groups’)-get() or similar